# Get a particular validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

I can get particular validator using

Page.Validators[0]

Can anyone tell me is there a way to get a specific validator searching using its ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for any control on the page using `FindControl`. It returns a `Control` so you'll need to cast it to it's proper type:

```
var rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator)Page.FindControl("rfv");
```

If the control exists within a container you'll need to find it from that container's control collection rather than from the `Page`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a validator on your front-end, like:

```
<asp:SomeValidator ID="vField" ... runat="server" />
```

You can just access that validator in your code-behind like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vField.Property = "value";
}
```